# Java: If file doesn´t exist I can´t create condition for file exist or not. Why?

Tags: java, file, if-statement, file-exists

Hi this is a simple code that compares whether a folder exists or not.

```
import java.io.*;

public class myfile {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        // Get the file
        File f = new File("file_f.txt");

        // Check if the specified file
        // Exists or not
        if (file_f.exists())
            System.out.println("Exists");
        else
            System.out.println("Does not Exists");
            System.out.println("I would like to run this possibility");
    }
}
```

But I need the code to be executed when the folder does not exist. But if I delete creating folder, It get an error ...
(In my code, I need to check if the folder exists and if not, the code has started to execute.) So how do I do it if in some cases the folder does not already exist?

Now I deleted creating file, because I would like to run else part...

```
import java.io.*;

public class myfile {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        // Get the file

        //File f = new File("friends.txt");



        // Check if the specified file
        // Exists or not
        if (file_f.exists())
            System.out.println("Exists");
        else
            System.out.println("Does not Exists");
            System.out.println("I would like to run this possibility");
    }
}
```

but

> Error:(14, 13) java: cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   variable f
>     location: class myfile

So how do I do it if in some cases the folder does not already exist?
Thank you

Comment: When you say folder do you mean the File file_f or some other File object that is not defined in this code?  Also, your code snippets reference file_f but that object is not defined anywhere.  When you declare File f in the first snippet is that supposed to be File file_f?

Comment: not able to interpret the question

Comment: Aside from main question, Java is not like Python where indentation defines scope. In Java scope is described by code block created via `{..}` brackets. So your `else` should probably be `else { /*those printing statements*/ }`

Answer (score 2):

This line doesn't create file on a disk (or whatever storage you are using).

```
File f = new File("friends.txt");
```

It just creates an object inside JVM which you may use for manipulations with file. To actually create a file from scratch you need to create a kind of `OutputStream` around that file and write something there and then close the stream.

Comment: And how do I know if a file created like this exists or not?
Not on disk, just in the application a txt.

Comment: You can call f.exists()

Comment: @david751 But `f` and actual file on a disc are two separate things. `f` is an *variable* of type File which represents *information of possible location* of file, it doesn't enforce existence of file or directory. You can write `new File("h:\\foo\\bar.txt")` and this will NOT enforce creation of `H:` drive/partition, or even if such drive already exist it will NOT enforce creating file in specified path. In other words there is no reason to remove `File f = new File("friends.txt");` from your code which means you can call `f.exist()`.

Comment: @david751 if you want to know if somebody else uses the filename `friends.txt` in the project then you need to use text search. `File.exists()` checks present of file with given name on file system not the fact that somebody else uses the same file name in Java project.

Answer (score 0):

This code will fix the compile error you mentioned and demonstrate functionality when a file is present and when it is not present

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileTester {
    private static void testFile(File f){
         // Check if the specified file
        // Exists or not
        if (f.exists())
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + " exists");
        else
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + " does not exist");        
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // assuming friends.txt already exists in current directory, this
        // will print "friends.txt exists"
        testFile(new File("friends.txt"));
        //assuming otherFile.txt does not already exist in current directory
        // this will print "otherFile.txt does not exist"
        testFile(new File("otherFile.txt"));

    }
}
```